# Babylon.js remove light reflection of Sphere

Tags: javascript, light, babylonjs

How can I remove reflection of (point) light from sphere in Babylon.js?

```
// Point light.
const light = new BABYLON.PointLight('myLight', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene)

// Sphere with size 100.
const newBox = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere('mySphere', 64, 100, scene)
```

I would like to light up half of sphere, but without reflection in the red circle:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution:

```
newBox.material = someMaterial
newBox.material.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: What you actually do, is to reduce the [Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model) to a [Lambertian diffuse reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance), by eliminating the specular highlights of the phong model.

Comment: so helpful this line :)